# Opposite signed solutions to same integral?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Say I have an integral:

$$\int\sqrt{(\sin x - \cos x)^2}\,dx$$

Now this can be evaluated into $\sin(x) - \cos(x)$ **or** $\cos(x) - \sin(x)$, right?
Although, in the end, I'm getting an opposite sign to the questions given in the textbook.
The two solutions look different as the signs are opposite, so which one is the right one?

**Edit:** The Original problem was the integral of $\sqrt{1-\sin2x}$.
This could be further expanded into $\sqrt{\sin^2x + \cos^2x-2\sin(x)\cos(x)}$.
Now, according to me, this can be written as $\sqrt{(\sin x - \cos x)^2}$ or $\sqrt{(\cos x - \sin x)^2}$. So, am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now this can be evaluated into $\sin(x) - \cos(x)$ **or** $\cos(x) - \sin(x)$, right?

**Wrong**.

$\sqrt{x^2}$ is not equal to "$x$ or $-x$". It is equal to $|x|$.

---

Remember, $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the **positive** solution to the equation $x^2=a$, and the positive solution to $x^2=a^2$ is $|a|$.

---

**After your edit**

You aren't wrong, in fact, $$\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}=\sqrt{(\sin x - \cos x)^2}=\sqrt{(\cos x - \sin x)^2}$$

But if you want to calculate the integral, then you will additionally have to change that into

$$|\sin x - \cos x|$$

(or, alternatively, into $|\cos x - \sin x|$ since it's the same thing) and separate some cases.

Comment: I think there’s a misunderstanding, I wasn’t talking about the evaluation of √x². Let me edit the question

Comment: @AlphaMineron I know you weren't but my point still applies. Whatever $x$ is, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is equal to $|x|$.

Comment: I've edited the question, btw is the negative solution of $x^2 = a^2$ equal to $-|a|$

Comment: @AlphaMineron And I updated my answer. And yes, I know the negative solution to $x^2=a^2$ is equal to $-|a|$, but $\sqrt{a^2}$ is still $|a|$.

Comment: Just a heads-up: I’ve suggested an edit that alters the format of what you quoted $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\left(\cos(x)-\sin(x)\right)^2=\sqrt{2}^2\cos^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$